# TTF_RenderText locks up

Tags: c, sdl, truetype

Writing a SDL program using TRueType fonts. I call `TTF_Init()` to initialize TTF and open my font with `TTF_OpenFont( name, size )`.

I have a routine that inserts null terminated text strings into a listbox using 
`sdl_surface=TTF_RenderText_Solid( font, data, sdl_color)`. This routine works for I then blit the surface to my `listbox` surface and delete the one returned from RenderText. I do this over and over again and it works most of the time. But on the 11th string entered it hangs. No errors just locks up the program. I know this is not much to go on but I am stuck.

Comment: You should post the minimal amount code that can reproduce this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling SDL_FreeSurface?

```
if (sdl_surface != NULL) SDL_FreeSurface(sdl_surface);
sdl_surface=TTF_RenderText_Solid( font, data, sdl_color)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as it turns out the problem was in another routine with memory allocation offsets. Once I found that this went away.